# Windows Forms Combo Box Changed Event

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

I have a Windows Form project, and I am looking to fire an event whenever the contents of a combo box are changed. The default event handler, `SelectedIndexChanged`, works fine when the user selects an item from a dropdown menu, but is not fired if the user manually types something in. I have tried other, similar events listed [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but none of them have the required behavior. How can I fire an event under both circumstances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event you are looking for is `TextChanged`. This event isn't listed as a ComboBox event because it is inherited; however, the full list can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox_events%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). To add this event, place the following line in your Form constructor, after `InitializeComponents()`:

```
yourComboBox->TextChanged += 
gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::yourComboBox_TextChanged);
```

There is no need to duplicate code between `TextChanged` and the default `SelectedIndexChanged`. The TextChanged event will be fired both for manual text changes and for changes via the dropdown.